Mesh on Cuboid[]
g = Graphics3D[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {3, 2, 1}]]
How do I draw mesh lines on this cuboid? In my application this is a 3x2x1 cuboid, made up of six cubes (each 1x1x1, of course). Can I easily draw lines on "g" to show this?
The first (top) cuboid at this link https://projecteuler.net/problem=126
shows the effect I am after.

BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {3, 2, 1}],   MaxCellMeasure -> 1]

@cvgmt Nice! I didn't know such a method exits.  The discretization only by squares, not by triangles, is guaranteed by this code? Depends on the shape?

How about drawing six cubes with highlighted edges?
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Dashed, Thick, Blue]], 
  Flatten@Table[
    Cuboid[{i, j, k}, {i + 1, j + 1, k + 1}], {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 
     1}, {k, 0, 0}]}]



This is an easy way to draw many cuboids, yielding the same effect:
Graphics3D[
 Translate[Cuboid[], Tuples[Range /@ {3, 2, 1}]]
]



How about customizing Cuboid[ ] like this?
ClearAll[myCuboid];
myCuboid[{p1_Integer,p2_Integer,p3_Integer},
{q1_Integer,q2_Integer,q3_Integer}] := (Cuboid /@ 
    Tuples[{Range[p1,q1-1],Range[p2,q2-1],Range[p3,q3-1]}]);

Graphics3D[myCuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {3, 2, 1}]]


